# Add image attachment to post via coding?

Tags: attachments, gallery, images

I tried to add an image as Attachment image to a post.
in `wp_postmeta` i added `_wp_attached_file` as `meta_key` and `value = productimages/Routers/v/CISCO1941.jpg`
it not works and i could not see the image as attachment! but when i use add image button in  wordpress's HTML editor, it add exactly this field to that table but with a different post ID!

is there any dependency for that field?
screenshot from db: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVlse.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not add image attachment **to** post. In WordPress image attachment **is also** post. See [post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) in Codex.

- what is usually called *post* on surface is technically post of `post` post type.
- image attachment is a post of `attachment` post type.

So what you need to do is to create image attachment (using [`wp_insert_attachment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) and couple more related functions) and set your post as parent for it.

Comment: Ofcourse you can! He meant to ask adding a independent uploaded image to be attached to a post, just like how you can do it in Media library.

Comment: @Ashfame that was not how I understood the question, will leave up to Amino to clarify. Anyway my answer does cover how to make it attached - set post as parent for it.

Comment: @Rarst: If i have a post id `$post_id` and `$attachment_id`, what is the function to add the parent as `$post_id` for `$attachment_id`?

Comment: @Sisir I don't remember if there is function for it. Technically it's `post_parent` field in posts table that holds ID of parent.

Comment: Hey, I made one :) here it is http://pastebin.com/nVVE2Bvq You think wordpress should have a function like this? Can we add it to trac?

Answer (score 6):

Like what Rarst mentioned, you technically want to set the attachment's `post_parent` value to the ID of the post you are attaching it to.

e.g. you can do something like this:

```
wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $attachment_id,
        'post_parent' => $post_id
    )
);
```

However, please take note of the [caution](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post#Caution.21) when using wp_update_post.

Another method using $wpdb

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query(
    "
    UPDATE $wpdb->posts 
    SET post_parent = $post_id
    WHERE ID = $attachment_id
        AND post_type = 'attachment'
    "
);
```